# Connecting MongoDB with Android Application using Java

Tags: java, android, mongodb

I am currently developing an Android application which uses the real time data from a remote server in JSON format. So, I planned to use MongoDB as the remote server. But, the problem is I need the **data to be returned** on accessing a specific URI as like CouchDB. But, some MongoDB docs state that connecting to a JAVA application needs a specific driver.

So, how can I return the data on request(by usage of any middlewares) and also are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please **Don't** do this.

You want a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API for your mobile application to connect to.

You **do not want** to connect your *database* directly to your mobile application. It has **never** been and will not ever come to be a reasonable way to do things.

Use a server side API, there are suggestions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) among other things you can possibly find (try google) or can implement yourself. REST api's are not hard.

Comment: how can I deploy it in real world? I use OpenShift and there are no options for that.

Comment: How **all** experienced people do it. You implement the API as a "go-between" for your "client" and the database "server". You **never** directly connect. This is a common principle.

Comment: What do you know how to program in? Java = Tomcat, etc etc. Node, Python, Ruby, Perl, PHP... the list goes on. Server side code your API. And **do not** connect directly to databases.